# Disabling SecureBoot in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I decided to move to Ubuntu, after getting a nasty ransomware and losing all of my data. I read in a forum that I must disable Secure Boot in BIOS in order to install drivers for graphics, sound etc. Is that correct? If yes, will I be vulnerable to any malware with Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: You don't have to disable SB unless you need proprietary drivers, it is not always the case. And disabling SB does not affect security ))

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Right now I am in the installation screen. I ticked the 3rd party drivers and I am asked to turn off Secure Boot. What should I do?

Comment: anything is the ubuntu repos will work with secure boot on (main, universe, and restricted). the main function of secure boot, is to insure that your boot code and  core system hasn't been modified (rootkit protection).

Comment: @xRpmX13 Disable Secure Boot, that is easier, or don't check 3rt party drivers. You can install them later if you really need them.

Comment: I plan to install AMD drivers, which will probably need SecureBoot disabled.  WIll there be any issue if I keep it disabled? I want to install all required drivers and at the same time be protected from malware.

Comment: I don't think there would be a real issue ...user permission restriction keeps rootkit from being installed also. But, if you want. read up on Dkms, It isn't very complicated and can sign the modules it produces from source. as well as automatically recompile with kernel upgrades.

Comment: @ravery How do you know that DKMS can sign? It is theoretically possible, but it is not very easy to do.

Comment: @pilot -- it doesn't need to be signed with a windows key since it is the kernel doing the verifying not SB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to disable secure boot.

Yes and no: Ubuntu is impervious to Windows malware unless you install [wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/index.php).

Yes, Ubuntu is vulnerable to ransomware [and it already has happened](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/erebus-resurfaces-as-linux-ransomware/), but **the risk is extremely low!**

Comment: Counter: Linux is not necessarily impervious to Windows viruses. It *could* be possible that some Windows malware is a specially-crafted file that can also cause damage to Linux systems if the file is read (e.g. the icon parse library). Similarly, Windows malware *may* have "linux detection" to trigger a different payload (this would be find more in PDFs). Finally, ransomware on Linux is definitely possible due to the fact that many major companies use Linux servers. It's also [already happened](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/erebus-resurfaces-as-linux-ransomware/).

Comment: As per comments in the edit history: Comment incorporated in answer and as per chat, but stating it here as well: multi-platform ransomware: yes. (e.G. programmed in java) but "Windows" ransomware: nah, not really.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need to disable Secure Boot in order to install specific drivers (due to kernel code-signing requirements). You *could* use custom signatures as well, though this does have the side effect of being a [*massive bloody pain*](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/installdriver.html#SigningTheNvidi485ac).

As for malware... this one is a doozy. For all *practical* intents and purposes, Windows malware will not affect Linux significantly (if at all), unless run with `wine`, a virtual machine, or similar. Same goes for ransomware.

---

***However,*** it's good to always understand the threats completely, and from every angle. It *is* theoretically possible for Windows malware to have specially-crafted portions for the explicit purpose of targeting Linux installations.

For example, a potential exploit path for a Windows/Linux virus contained within a `.exe` is Nautilus' EXE icon generation. In theory, a well-crafted malicious program could exploit this icon generator into running arbitrary code that would run and install some form of malware onto Linux. This combined with a few other exploits would allow for a full installation of malware onto your Linux machine without anyone even knowing. Such an exploit is more-or-less theoretical, but still a possibility. In order for this to work, the malware would have to be written with some awareness (and intent) to target Linux as well, even if its primary goal is to infect Windows computers.

The same principle can apply elsewhere, too. For example, a PDF that contains a malware bootstrapper could have Linux-specific instructions that are executed when you open your PDF. This already has been seen in the wild a couple times, so care is still advised.

As for ransomware. Linux *is* a pretty massive target for ransomware due to its nature and its widespread usage in large datacenters by major companies. Ransomware [has already been seen in the wild](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/erebus-resurfaces-as-linux-ransomware/) for Linux, and this trend will only increase as time goes on.

It's important to remember that while Linux is more secure by default due to its multi-user design and isolation principles, it's not a replacement for anti-malware practices and common sense. You *need* to keep this in mind with any system and employ the standard common-sense principles of using a firewall, not clicking on weird links, and so on.